# Como transformar expressões lambdas em comandos sql?

Tags: c#, sql, expressões-lambda, linq-to-sql

Como posso manipular as expressões para ajudar a automatizar a criação de comandos SQL como faz o Linq to SQL?

Assim: usando o EntityFramework eu consigo fazer consultas tais como:

```
var livros = contexto.Livros
   .Where(livro => livro.SaldoEstoque > 0)
   .OrderBy(livro => livro.Preco);

livros.ToList(); // nesse momento a query é executada
```

Como posso usar esse tipo de recurso para automatizar minhas consultas?

Exemplo:

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte classe:

```
public abstract GenericDAL<TModel> where T : class
{
    private SqlConnection _connection = null;
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    private string query;

    public GenericDAL()
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString);
        TableName = "Nome da Tabela";
    }

    public GenericDAL<TModel> Query()
    {
        query = "";
        query = "select * from " + TableName;
        return this;
    }

    public GenericDAL<TModel> OrderBy(Expression<Func<TModel, object>> byProp)
    {
        // como adicionar a expressão à query?
        return this;
    }

    public List<TModel> ToList()
    {
        // executa a query e cria a lista
    }
}
```

E então, poder fazer assim:

```
var dao = new GenericDAL<Livro>();
dao.Query().OrderBy(livro => livro.Preco).ToList();
```

Comment: Essa questão é praticamente "Como criar um ORM?". O que você está realmente querendo fazer é isso?

Comment: Não, quero flexibilizar minha camada DAO. Os exemplos são meramente ilustrativo.

Comment: Sem haver um mapeamento objeto-relacional, é impossível você gerar uma query. Você tem duas opções: permitir um mapeamento configurável, ou então adotar algum tipo de convenção... algo do tipo **"o nome da propriedade é igual ao nome da coluna"** é uma convenção. Também teria de definir o que acontece quando houver objetos intermediários na lambda: **`dao.OrderBy(x => x.OutroObjeto.Nome)`**... você quer dar suporte para isso? Qualquer das opções já é um ORM (um mini-ORM assim por dizer).

Comment: Eu já sigo um padrão. Minhas colunas e tabelas possuem os nomes das propriedades e classes. Sobre dar suporte para objetos intermediários, eu posso até ver se tem condições de fazer isso. Mas, gostaria primeiro de saber como fazer o OrderBy. Não quero ORM, mas se vai pegar algumas características do que seria uma ORM, com isso não estou me importando.

Comment: Afinal de contas, fica muito simples de fazer. Dá até para pensar em objetos intermediários, criar outros tipos de métodos como LeftJoin e InnerJoin ao invés de apenas Order By.
Dá até para  criar um Where também.

Answer (score 1):

Só de seguir um padrão para os nomes na hora de criar a expressão lambda e fazendo o seguinte código eu já consegui obter um bom resultado.

```
public GenericDAL<TModel> OrderBy(Expression<Func<TModel, object>> byProp)
    {
        query += " order by " + byProp.Body.ToString();
        return this;
    }
```

Exemplo:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dao = new GenericDAL<Livro>();
        dao.Query().OrderBy(Livro => Livro.Nome);
        Console.WriteLine(dao.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Resultado:

```
select * from Livro order by Livro.Nome
```

Nada difícil.

---

Descobri uma forma que deixa o resultado ainda mellhor. Assim:

```
    public GenericDAL<TModel> OrderBy(Expression<Func<TModel, object>> byProp)
    {
        var expression = byProp.Body as dynamic;
        var termOfExpression = expression.Expression.Name;

        query += " order by " + byProp.Body.ToString().Replace(termOfExpression + ".", "");
        return this;
    }
```

O comando fica assim:

```
select * from Livro order by Nome
```

mesmo que eu use como expressão lambda algo como:

```
dao.Query.OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```